# PayPal IPN subscr_payment_skippped transaction type

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using Paypal enhanced recurring payment for my subscriptions and also set up the IPN handler and the messages are logged in my database. On checking the PayPal IPN variables documentation, i got confused between two variables

> subscr_payment

and

> recurring_payment

According to my knowledge, the former is used in case of website payment standards enhanced recurring payment and the latter is used when the recurring profile is created via an api call. Are my conclusion on these variables correct.

Secondly i  could see a trasaction type as

> recurring_payment_skipped

But the same equivalent for subscription payment is not found ie

> subscr_payment_skipped

So since i am using Enhanced recurring payment and if any skipped payment occurs what would be my transaction type?.

I couldn't mock this case

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated